# Does internal state "leak" when it influences externally-visible behavior?

Tags: c++, state, const

I have a method (in C++) which generates a value based on a parameter and the parameters from previous calls. Calling it more than once with the same parameter may generate different values each time. For example:

```
public:

    int getValue(const int param)
    {
        int value = param ^ previousParam;
        previousParam = param;
        return value;
    }

private:

    int previousParam;
```

Does it make sense to allow this method to be called on `const` objects? Is `previousParam` part of the object's internal state, or does it "leak" since the internal state affects the object's external behavior?

I think of this method like a generator that just creates a series of values on subsequent calls, rather than a method which modifies the object. The caller is not supposed to depend on a particular parameter generating a specific value. Would it be sensible to change the declarations to the following?

```
int getValue(const int param) const;
mutable int previousParam;
```

Comment: what about using a static variable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some good answers here already, but I think there is something more to say about your "mental model" of the object, since you wrote

> I think of this method like a generator that just creates a series of values on subsequent calls, rather than a method which modifies the object.

But since `previousParam` is a member of your object, the method actually *does* modify the object. However, in your mental model, `previousParam` seems not to be part of the object. So I guess your real problem is that the whole `getValue` method including the `previousParam` member is misplaced - it should probably be part of a different class, which provides an abstraction for your generator, and where `getValue` is naturally a non-const method.

Answer (score 2):

`const` only "guarantees" that an object's members don't change. Nothing stops you from making `const` methods that depend on mutable state outside of the object (e.g. a global variable). However, most people expect `const` to mean that the object's state won't change when you call `const` methods on it. Since you're not supposed to know about an object's members, and since you can cheat with the `mutable` keyword, its state is effectively what it returns from its methods. Thus a `const` method that changes what the object returns in future calls will definitely surprise people.

If you want a "generator" that returns a sequence of values, then return a different non-`const` object (preferably an iterator) that contains your original object's state.

Answer (score 2):

There are three good reasons to not make `getValue` const.

1. Principle of least astonishment - I would find it very, very surprising to discover that a `const` method caused an externally visible change in the behavior of the object (even if I'm not supposed to depend on a particular parameter generating a specific value).
2. Logical versus physical `const` - There's some discussion as to whether `const` should indicate *logically* constant (no change in the visible state or behavior) or *physically* constant (bitwise identical). `getValue` is obviously not physically const, and since the visible behavior changes, it's hard to see how you could make a case for logical const (even if callers aren't supposed to depend on a particular parameter generating a specific value).
3. `const` in C++11 - C++11 has tightened the semantics of `const` to mean, approximately, "usable in a thread-safe fashion." (This is an oversimplification; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14127379/25507), [here](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/24/gotw-6a-const-correctness-part-1-3/), and [here](http://codecraft.co/2013/01/02/how-sutters-wrong-about-const-in-cpp-11/) for details and discussion.) `getValue` isn't thread-safe and so isn't be `const` in the sense C++11 expects `const` to mean.  (Whether you need to comply with this C++11 meaning of `const` depends on your application.)

Comment: It doesn't cause a change in external behaviour if you don't depend on the return value. So there's no reason to consider that it's not logically `const` or astonishing that it would be `const`.

Comment: @DeadMG - Understood, but even if I'm not depending on specific return values, I expect code to be deterministic: to always return the same output given the same state and the same input. I control the input, and `const` should describe the logical state, so barring any external I/O, global variables, etc., I believe varying outputs while `const` would be a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I think that depends on the semantics of the object.

If it is a random number generator or similar, `RandGen` say, then what would it mean for a `RandGen` object to be `const`? Is the object usable at all if it were `const`?

For example, you might have a member method to set the seed, which I would consider should be non-`const`. Then it might make sense for `getValue` to be `const`:

```
void setSeed(long seed);
```

Another example might be a function which accepts a `RandGen` object and checks whether its internal `param` is *"sufficiently random"*. We likely do not want `isSufficientlyRandom` to call `getValue`, and so `getValue` might be non-`const` here:

```
bool isSufficientlyRandom(const RandGen& randGen) {
    return randGen.getPreviousParam() > 17; 
}
```